# Retina icons with jQTouch

Tags: iphone, ios4, icons, jqtouch, retina-display

Anyone knows how I can replace the orignial icon with the retina version of it, if the user have a iOS with retina display?

I've tried with data-mask="[name]@2x.[ext]" but without luck.
Hope someone have a solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to include two files in your project: `image.png` and `image@2x.png`. But it's not necessary to write `@2x`-suffix in code. Just:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

iOS will automatically detect, what image should be used.

Comment: Problem is, that I'm coding with jQTouch and Phonegap :-)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Well, try to do smth like this: http://flowz.com/2010/07/css-image-replacement-for-iphone-4-high-dpi-retina-display/

Comment: Looks like it's working, but the icon on retina displays seems to be to big, even if I just set the size to x2 of the original image.
It should just scale it up in quality, but that's not the case here.

As you can see here: http://d.pr/P7an
Any suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following approach:

1. Assuming I want to display a 100x40 px height image
2. Create a single image, 200x80 px
3. Specify a css width of 100 px and height of 40 px for the image

On non retina displays this will stretch the original image to 50%. For my personal taste the result looks more than OK.

On retina displays this will practically result in a 1-to-1 mapping between image pixels and device (real) pixels.

I have to mention that I didn't test this with Phonegap, but used it in a MonoTouch project, with a web container.